# How can I know when the "Back" button was pressed?

Tags: objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uistoryboard

I use storyboard with identifier, when i want to call some view, I use this code:

```
ViewB *view = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"View2"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController: view animated:YES];
```

But I want to do something when i pressed the back button, How can I know that happens this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That depends on what you are really up to.

First of all you cannot directly catch such an event or so. Unless you replace the back button with your own back button, assign yours to an action of yours and go from there. Within this action you can perform what ever you want to do. And you will have to care for calling `popViewControllerAnimated:` yourself.

If you don't really need to know that the button was pressed and just need to react when ever the view controller or its view respectively disappears then you can overwrite `viewWillDisappear` or `viewDidDisappear`. But be aware that these methods are called too every time when another view is pushed ontop of your very view.

`viewWillUnload` or `viewDidUnload` is probably more what you are looking for.

However, `dealloc` is called when the view controller is destroyed.

One of these will do depending on what you really need.

Comment: Can't I do something directly with the event back .. so I have to do my own back button. I need my button because i need to pass to the back view some value.

Comment: Why can't you pass that value in viewWillDisappear or viewWillUnload?

Comment: I used my own button because when I used viewWillDisappear didn't happend that I expected , i passed the parameters.. but i prefer do my own back button, thanks